# R: Using a variable to to pass multiple values for a single dynamically-defined parameter into a function

Tags: r, parameter-passing, microbenchmark

I would like to be able to pass a parameter through two functions, but defining the parameter that is use with a variable. This would avoid having to specify every possibility of what the parameter could be.

See the following example for what I'd like to achieve:

```
run_multiple <- function (parameter_name, parameter_values) {
  for (value in parameter_values) {
    run_function(parameter_name = value)
  }
}

run_function <- function (x = "a", y = "a", z = "a") {
  print(sprintf("X is %s, Y is %s, Z is %s", x, y, z))
}
```

Then implementation would ideally work using either of these formats:

```
run_multiple("x", c("a", "b"))
run_multiple(x, c("a", "b"))
# [1] X is a, Y is a, Z is a
# [1] X is b, Y is a, Z is a
```

The above would call `run_function(x = "a")` and `run_function(x = "b")` within the loop of `run_multiple`.

I don't think `...` notation in `run_multiple` would help as far as I can tell, as it would only allow me to pass through the single value, not multiple values in the loop.

If it's useful, the wider context of this is to be used alongside microbenchmarking for a large function, to see how enabling different versions of sub-functions affects the overall performance.

Example of how this works:

```
run_benchmarking <- function (parameter_name, parameter_values, run_names) {
  # currently setup with only two values allowed
  microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
      run_names[1] = run_function(parameter_name = parameter_values[1]),
      run_names[2] = run_function(parameter_name = parameter_values[2]),
    times = 1000
  )
}

run_function <- function (use_x = T, use_y = T, use_z = T) {
  x <- func1(use_x)
  y <- func2(use_y)
  z <- func3(use_z)
  
  list(x = x, y = y, z = z)
}

# example of func n
func1 <- function (use_x) {
  if (use_x) {
    x <- round(runif(1, 1, 100))
  } else {
    x <- 1
  }
}

# example of benchmarking tests, which would output results from microbenchmark
run_benchmarking(use_x, c(T, F), c("With X", "Without X"))
run_benchmarking(use_y, c(T, F), c("With Y", "Without Y"))
run_benchmarking(use_z, c(T, F), c("With Z", "Without Z"))
```

This currently only accepts two values into a parameter which is something that could be expanded, but should be sufficient for A/B testing initially.

I'm also open to other suggestions if there's a better way to test over a number of A/B tests like this.

Comment: Are you tring to reinvent [profiling](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/218221837-Profiling-R-code-with-the-RStudio-IDE)? I don't really understand what you want to achive. How is the output from `run_multiple("x", c("a", "b"))` related to the input? Why are `y` and `z` set to `"a"`?

Comment: @Roland definitely not trying to reinvent profiling! From what I've attempted, profiling helped with understanding where bottlenecks are in the code, but less so with A/B testing different options.

Good point with y/z being "a", that was a typo on my part.

run_multiple("x", c("a", "b")) would ideally run run_function(x = "a") and run_function(x = "b")

I'll clarify this in an edit as well, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
run_multiple <- function (parameter_name, parameter_values) {
  parameter_name <- as.character(substitute(parameter_name))
  for (value in parameter_values) {
    arg <- setNames(list(value), parameter_name)
    do.call(run_function, arg)
  }
}

run_function <- function (x = "a", y = "a", z = "a") {
  print(sprintf("X is %s, Y is %s, Z is %s", x, y, z))
}

run_multiple("x", c("a", "b"))
#[1] "X is a, Y is a, Z is a"
#[1] "X is b, Y is a, Z is a"
run_multiple(x, c("a", "b"))
# [1] X is a, Y is a, Z is a
# [1] X is b, Y is a, Z is a
```

This can be extended to multiple parameter names. Of course that would be easier without non-standard evaluation because then you could just use a vector of parameter names and a list or matrix of corresponding value vectors as input.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `do.call` which allows for variable args to be passed through to a function. This also allows for the expansion into allowing multiple parameters to be passed through and parsed (e.g. `use_x` and `use_y`)

```
run_benchmarking <- function (parameter_combinations, run_names) {
  benchmark_list <- alist(
      do.call(run_function, list(eval(parse(text = parameter_combinations[1])))),
      do.call(run_function, list(eval(parse(text = parameter_combinations[2]))))
  )
  
  names(benchmark_list) = run_names
  
  # currently setup with only two values allowed
  microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    list = benchmark_list,
    times = 1000
  )
}
```

This can then be called with:

```
run_benchmarking(c("use_x = T", "use_x = F"), c("With X", "Without X"))

# Unit: microseconds
#      expr  min   lq    mean median   uq   max neval
#     With X 15.0 15.5 17.7892   15.8 16.4 138.5  1000
#  Without X 14.1 14.7 16.5617   14.9 15.4 185.4  1000
```

Comment: If you are using `eval(parse(...))`, you are doing it wrong. Code using this approach is difficult to debug (because you don't get useful error messages) and `parse` is very slow.

Comment: @Roland I definitely agree! I don't like this solution at all, but I've included it as an example of something that at least works for the desired outcome. Do you have any pointers in a direction I could go and research?